# ajax and jquery display two different message on same div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My problem is that I have two messages:

- **error message**
- **success message**

Here with the help of jQuery, I fetch the email field value and want to check whether email exits in the database or not.

If exits then show success message, otherwise show error message.

```
$('#email').blur(function(){

        var err_msg_css={"background-color":"#FDE4E1","border":"1px solid #FBD3C6","border-radius":"10px 4px 4px 10px","color":"#CB4721","font-size": "14px","float":"left","font-family":"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif","font-size":"small","font-style":"oblique","height":"22px","margin-left":"6px","padding":"3px","width":"196px"};
        var sucess_msg_css={"background-color":"#D5FFC6","border":"1px solid #C0F0B9","border-radius":"10px 4px 4px 10px","color":"#48A41C","font-size": "14px","float":"left","font-family":"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif","font-size":"small","font-style":"oblique","height":"22px","margin-left":"6px","padding":"3px","width":"196px"};

        var text = /[a-z]$/;
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        var email=$('#email').val();

        if(!$('#email').val()){
            $('#err_msg_9').html('<img src="css/images/error.jpg">email field is empty').css(err_msg_css).show();
            return false;
        }else{

            if(!pattern.test(email)){
                //console.log('qwerty')
                $('#err_msg_9').html('<img src="css/images/error.jpg">email is not valid').css(err_msg_css).show();
                return false;
            }else{
                var Email=$("#email").val();
                var datatype = 'email='+ Email;

                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax_centre.php",
                    data: datatype,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $("#err_msg_9").html(html);
                    } 
                });

                //$('#err_msg_9').html('<img src="css/images/success.jpg">sucessful').css(sucess_msg_css).show();    
                //
                return false;
            }
        }
        //$('#err_msg_1').hide();

        return true;

    });
```

PHP

```
if($_POST['email'])
{
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $counter=0;

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT `email` FROM `form_value` WHERE `email`='$email'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        if($email == $row['email']){ 
            $counter = 1;
            //echo "email is already in use";
        }else{
            //echo "email is unique";    
        }                        
    }
}


//error message
$('#err_msg_9').html('<img src="css/images/error.jpg">email is not valid').css(err_msg_css).show();
//success message
$('#err_msg_8').html('<img src="css/images/success.jpg">sucessful').css(sucess_msg_css).show();
```

Comment: As an English note: it's "message", not ["massage"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massage). :-)

Comment: So where is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Change your `Email` to `email` and in your Ajax call, you are only adding the message, successful or not, to the same id `#err_msg_9`, you need to check what is the message first and than you decide where to put it

Comment: i want to know can i pass some value from ajax_centre.php page to form.php(main page).if(success){pass like value 1}else {pass like value 1} from ajax_centre.php to form.php.this 1 and 0 value use in jquery validation

Answer (score 1):

JSON is useful for this time.

Client code:

```
 $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_centre.php",
            data: datatype,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {
                try{
                    json = $.parseJSON(html);
                }catch(e){}
                if( typeof json !== 'object' ){
                    alert(html);
                    return false;
                }
                if( ! json.success ){
                    var html = '<img src="css/images/error.jpg">' + json.message;
                    $("#err_msg_9").html(html).css(err_msg_css).show();
                }else{
                    var html = '<img src="css/images/success.jpg">' + json.message;
                    $("#err_msg_8").html(html).css(sucess_msg_css).show();
                }
            } 
        });
```

*Server Code:*

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$response = array();
    if( !empty($row) && $email === $row['email']){ 
        $counter = 1;
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "email is already in use";
    }else{
        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "email is unique";
    } 
echo json_encode($response);
```